# How to run Spark jobs in Apache Airflow running in Docker?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to run some spark job in airflow. I am running airflow in docker and have one master and one worker container (pulled official apache spark image from docker hub). I specified spark (master) url (spark/containerid:7077) in sparksubmit function but it’s giving me a Java Home not found error.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!!!

I did bash in spark master container and tried to spark submit my pyspark script there but it gives me ivy error. I was running like this : spark-submit —master spark//localhost:7077 —deploy mode client my _script.py
May b I am doing spark submit wrong !!

Answer (score 1):

In [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#example-of-adding-airflow-provider-package-and-apt-package) there's an example for creating docker image for spark.

Note that `JAVA_HOME` is also defined there:

```
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: @ShishirHossain does it answer your question? :)